# Dokku and Kubernetes: How to Build A PaaS?

Tags: kubernetes

I am fairly new to the world of DevOps. I am trying to build a platform that is similar to Heroku. I have gotten introduced to Dokku and Kubernetes and thought I might be able to install dokku on Kubernetes pods for each user. The pods will house the deployment of the user as they push their code using git. Is this the right approach? If not, then what is the best way to go about creating a platform similar to Heroku even at a smaller scale?